# Restore oldValue in tableview after editing the cell javaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview

Hi I am following the AddressBook example from Oracle site.

```
bookName.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Books, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Books, String> t) {
            if (t.getNewValue().equals("") || t.getNewValue().length() < 3) {
                info.setText("Book name must be greater than 3 characters.");
                // set the old value or do not update the cell.
                return;
            }
            ((Books) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setBookName(t.getNewValue());
        }
    }
);
```

The problem is If I edit a cell It just take the newvalue, but I do not want to update the cell value if string is empty of less than 3 char.

Comment: Are you tried with t.getOldValue();

Comment: Yes  t.getOldValue() return the old value but how to set it?

Comment: Try this -  ((Books)t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setBookName(t.getOldValue());

Comment: I tried it but still the cell show new value.

Answer (score 2):

When the backing datamodel is not updated but the tableview shows new edited value, it means that the tableview does not refreshed the rendered values. To force refresh do:

```
bookName.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Books, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Books, String> t) {
            if (t.getNewValue().equals("") || t.getNewValue().length() < 3) {
                info.setText("Book name must be greater than 3 characters.");

                // workaround for refreshing rendered values
                t.getTableView().getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
                t.getTableView().getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);

                // set the old value or do not update the cell.
                return;
            }
            ((Books) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setBookName(t.getNewValue());
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I know the question is old but in my opinion it is without proper answer and I came here looking for one.
In my opinion proper answer is like above that when you don't edit the model - value only changes inside table view. So you need to refresh table view. But why to do it with: `t.getTableView().getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false); t.getTableView().getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);` when you can just do it like below? `t.getTableView().refresh();`

Comment: @ŁukaszKotyński refresh might be introduced after this answer :) The basic problem is caused by a bug in TableCell (actually, all cells): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187314

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found the solution try mine:

Actually, the real item stay the same, although the table show the new value. So what I do is removing the item and set it with old one.

```
qtyColumn.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TestObject, Integer> event) -> {
TestObject to = event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow());
        try {
            if (event.getNewValue() < 0) {
                throw new Exception("You might wanna put error messages here");
            } else {
                to.setQty(event.getNewValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Make some dialog to show error
            event.getTableView().getItems().set(event.getTablePosition().getRow(), to);
        }
```

In my case it works.